# recover SOL from a Program Executable Data Account

Tags: solana-program, program

I have a program that I want to shut down and recover the SOL from.  There are two addresses associated with the program,  the program itself and the address of the executable data.

If i do:

solana program close BLA

using the CLI, and pass the program address (not the address of the executable data) will this recover the SOL present in the executable data account as well?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To put this quickly, yes! Here's an example flow against a test validator:

```
$ solana balance
500000000 SOL
$ solana program deploy spl_token_2022.so
Program Id: 5WTTsc3ySvMxRJ1zTgrV9F6p7rnEA7anZGh4ivW5jQfz
$ solana balance
499999980.753141761 SOL
$ solana program close --bypass-warning 5WTTsc3ySvMxRJ1zTgrV9F6p7rnEA7anZGh4ivW5jQfz

Closed Program Id 5WTTsc3ySvMxRJ1zTgrV9F6p7rnEA7anZGh4ivW5jQfz, 19.2388668 SOL reclaimed
$ solana balance
499999999.99200356 SOL
```

More info at https://docs.solana.com/cli/deploy-a-program#closing-program-and-buffer-accounts-and-reclaiming-their-lamports